# How to change the grub efi loader's grub.cfg location

Tags: boot, partition, grub2, configuration, uefi

This is the first time that I'm installing a grub efi loader, and I admit that things has been a mess.

I.e., as per [UEFI Grub not finding config file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/648089/uefi-grub-not-finding-config-file), *"GRUB loads grub.cfg **from the ESP** using an absolute path"*, e.g., `/EFI/debian/grub.cfg`, however I don't have any `grub.cfg` in my ESP partition.

```
$ find EFI/ | grep -v Microsoft/
EFI/
EFI/debian
EFI/debian/grubx64.efi
EFI/Microsoft
EFI/Boot
EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi
EFI/systemd
EFI/systemd/systemd-bootx64.efi
EFI/Linux
EFI/ubuntu
EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
```

I am wondering where they are, and I now try to understand how it boots, as I've lost track of that. The answer to [How does the grub efi loader find the correct grub.cfg and boot directory?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/267765/) looks into the `bootx64.efi` file, but I'm really not sure how relevant it is to my case as I'm getting:

```bsh
$ strings EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi | grep search.fs_uuid | wc
      0       0       0

$ strings EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi | grep search | wc
      0       0       0
```

Using `efibootmgr -v` doesn't reveal much how it is booting either. It only prints something like:

```
Boot0000* debian        HD(13,GPT,007a058a-8e5e-45df-8d97-6575b66b5355,0x1afa9000,0x113000)/File(\EFI\debian\grubx64.efi)
```

The `ubuntu` entry is quite similar too. My questions are, for the `ubuntu` entry,

- how can I know where its `grub.cfg` file is, and
- how can I change it, pointing to the one on another partition instead, and
- when grub boots, would that partition containing the `grub.cfg` file be considered as the default `root` by grub?

I want to switch `grub.cfg` file to the partition that contain a bunch of `.iso` files, and I want to know if I can assume that I can directly refer to those `.iso` files without trying to search for the partition first.

Comment: And your Debian version is?

Comment: I don't know how it is relevant to my ubuntu entry question, but my Debian version is 11 @ArtemS.Tashkinov.

Comment: I installed an older version of Debian a while back & it seemed to compile grub.cfg into the .efi boot file. Ubuntu have grub.cfg in /EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg for a full instal which is a configfile entry to full grub in /bootl. You can install grub using --removable and manually create your own grub.cfg to boot ISO. I did that for some smaller flash drives, but now usually do a full install & add ISO boot entries to grub in /boot. https://askubuntu.com/questions/549647/uefi-machine-doesnt-boot-ubuntu-through-nvram-bootcatalog-how-to-fix & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot/Examples